# provisioning profile problem?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-provisioning

i am running my apps with different provisioning profiles.(I am creating one
provisioning profile for each application an running in device). but i want to
run all applications in my device(without overwritting previous apps) with only one provisioning profile.I hope , it is possible.when we set apple id only in plist file as "com.myappleid.identifer(123145^&)" identifier will come uniquely automatically.can any one give simple tutorial to create the provisioning profile?
can i use my previous development certificate for that provisioning profile?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a wildcard provisioning profile. If all your apps start with the same identifier, e.g. com.myappleid.App1, com.myappleid.App2... then you can create a provisioning profile with the identifier com.myappleid.* which would match all of the above.

Comment: This works for me. I just created one for iPhones and one for iPads. Just because I could :-)

Comment: if i use wildcard, it will replace previous application, we can install only one appliaction in deveice?

Comment: A wildcard provisioning profile can be your "one provisioning profile" mentioned, and then every one of your apps, as long as it starts with the same prefix, can be provisioned to run with it.

Comment: @Mischa Correct. You can only install one version of an App on a device at a time (i.e. you can't have two different versions of your App on the same device, the latest copy would overwrite the old one.

You can, however, install more than one of your test apps on a single device, but just one copy of each app on a device is possible. I'm pretty certain about this, but there may be ways to circumvent this.